# How to add an Index on an VarChar-Array column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an Array column of varchar(256)-values:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD "subject" VARCHAR(256)[] NULL
```

And I want to query this field like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE subject && '{"journal", "book"}';
```

Since I want to query on values in that particular array, I need an index for performance reasons. However, every attempt failed due to missing storage classes or unsupported column type.

I have tried:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_daily_subject on "daily" USING GIN ("subject" gin_trgm_ops)
CREATE INDEX idx_daily_subject on "daily" USING GIN (to_tsvector('english', subject))
```

But then I receive the following error messages:

> ```
> ERROR: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type character varying[]
> ```

successive

> ERROR: function to_tsvector(unknown, character varying[]) does not
> exist

I found a workaround here: [Postgres - Indexing long character varying array type column using GIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809730/postgres-indexing-long-character-varying-array-type-column-using-gin)
but this makes any ORM mapper that I use obsolete (TypeORm in my case).

I have seen examples that for integer-arrays, there is a storage class available `gin__int_ops`. I couldn't find a suitable thing for `text` or `varchar`.

Is there anything that helps me?

Comment: Which operation are you trying to support?

Comment: @jjanes I want support a query like this  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE subject && '{"journal", "book"}';
I've updated my question accordingly, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

There is a default operator class for GIN for varchar[] which supports `&&`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_daily_subject on "daily" USING GIN ("subject")
```